# Uploading private files?

Tags: django-cms

I want to be able to upload files using django-cms, and have those files only be visible to authenticated users.

I've gotten as far as creating a "Members only" page, clicking "Login required" and selecting "for logged in users only" for Menu visibility ("advanced settings under /admin/cms/page).  This gets me some of what I want; the page itself is not visible unless you're logged in.  And the menu item goes away too.

But, the next step is a problem.  I can upload a file using the "file" plugin.  This puts the file under /media/cms_page_media/.  Even though you can't see the page which displays the link, you can still get to the file if you have the direct URL to it.  What I need is something which not only protects the page, but the files uploaded to it.

I know my way around most (well, some) of django, so I could do a bit of hacking to get a solution.  I'm hoping to avoid writing an entire file manager from scratch (not that it wouldn't make a nice little OSS project).

Answer (score 0):

Django Filer (https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer) has this option in the newest release. It also has a nice set of CMS Plugins which add a lot of value over the default File plugin: https://github.com/stefanfoulis/cmsplugin-filer